# Nuxt+Expressで取得した画像ファイルの表示ができない

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, express.js

NuxtでサーバからAPI経由で取得した画像ファイルの表示をさせようとしているのですが、何も表示されず。
しかし、開発環境で実行している最中にvueファイルを更新したタイミングなどで、画像が表示されます。
そこでリロードするとまた表示されない状態にはなってしまうという。

レスポンスを見るとデータは取得できているようなのですが、バインディングしている先に表示させるための方法が良くないのでしょうか。

しっかりとNuxtなりVue.jsの仕組みを理解しきれていないせいなのかもしれませんが、アドバイスいただけないでしょうか。
また、もしもっと良い仕組みがとり得るのであれば、教えていただけないでしょうか。

```
<img :src="item.imageContent" :key="item.imageContent" alt="取得した画像">
・・・
    data() {
      return {
        imageContent: null,
・・・
    const imagePath = this.item.image_path;
    const imageResponse = await this.$axios.get(`/api/imagecontent?path=${encodeURIComponent(imagePath)}`, { responseType: 'blob' });
    const imageContent = URL.createObjectURL(imageResponse.data); // 画像ファイルのデータは返ってきているように見えている
    this.item.imageContent = imageContent;
```

Comment: Vue.setで解決しました。
仕組み上、こうしないといけなかったものなのか、付け焼き刃的な対応なのかが分かっていないのですが。

const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageResponse.data);
・・・
this.$set(item, 'imageContent', imageURL);